# Django REST Framework generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView return all records instead of one

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework, drf-nested-routers

I'm new to DRF and trying to build a rest API, I have set up my models, URLs,  views, and serializers as:

> model.py:

```
services = (
    ('Single', 'Single'),
    ('Multiple', 'Multiple'),
)


class DeploymentOnUserModel(models.Model):
    deployment_name = models.CharField(max_length=256, )
    credentials = models.TextField(blank=False)
    project_name = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=False)
    project_id = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True)
    cluster_name = models.CharField(max_length=256, blank=False)
    zone_region = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=False)
    services = models.CharField(max_length=150, choices=services)
    configuration = models.TextField()
    routing = models.TextField()

    def save(self, **kwargs):
        if not self.id and self.services == 'Multiple' and not self.routing and not self.configuration:
            raise ValidationError("You must have to provide routing for multiple services deployment.")
        super().save(**kwargs)
```

> From urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path, include
# from .routers import router
from . import apiview

app_name = 'deployments'

urlpatterns = [
    # path('', include(router.urls), name='deployments'),
    path('deployments/', apiview.DeploymentsList.as_view(), name='deployment-list'),
    path('deployments/<int:pk>/', apiview.DeploymentDetail.as_view(), name='deployment_detail')

]
```

> From apiview.py:

```
class DeploymentDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):

    def retrieve(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        pk = self.kwargs.get('pk')

        return Response(DeploymentOnUserModel.objects.get(pk=kwargs['pk']))
```

> From serializers.py:

```
class DeploymentOnUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = DeploymentOnUserModel
        fields = '__all__'
```

When I try access: http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/deployments/?pk=1/ it should return a single object of **id=1** but it returns all objects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of pasing pk as GET argument you should pass it as part of url like this:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/deployments/1/
```

URL you are trying to use `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/deployments/?pk=1/` performed by `DeploymentsList` since it's not contain `pk` url kwarg.

Also you should serialize object before return it as response:

```
class DeploymentDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):

    def retrieve(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        pk = self.kwargs.get('pk')
        object = DeploymentOnUserModel.objects.get(pk=kwargs['pk'])
        serializer = DeploymentOnUserSerializer(object)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Comment: Hi @neverwalkaloner, it returns `page not found error`

Comment: @AbdulRehman try to add slash to urlpattern: `'deployments/<int:pk>/'`.

Comment: it still returns all objects!

Comment: Hi @neverwalkaloner, I have added the `urls.py` file.

Comment: When I try `get` method instead of `retrieve` the url error has gone but it return another error as: `Object of type 'DeploymentOnUserModel' is not JSON serializable`

Answer (score 0):

> When I try get method instead of retrieve the url error has gone but
> it return another error as: Object of type 'DeploymentOnUserModel' is
> not JSON serializable

I know it's late but in your apiview.py

```
class DeploymentDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    serializer_class = DeploymentOnUserSerializer()   

    
   def get_queryset(self):
      pk = self.request.GET.get("pk")
      return deployment = DeploymentOnUserModel.objects.get(pk=pk)
```