# Expected view UserDetails to be called with a URL keyword argument named "pk"

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-users, django-rest-framework-jwt

**models.py**

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    mobile = models.PositiveBigIntegerField(unique=True)

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.user.username
```

**serializers.py**

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['id', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'username', 'email']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(UserSerializer, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.Meta.depth = 1
```

**authentication.py**

```
class JWTAuthentication(BaseAuthentication):
    def authenticate(self, request):
        print('authenticating')
        auth = get_authorization_header(request).split()
        print(auth)
        if auth and len(auth) == 2:
            token = auth[1].decode('utf-8')
            print('Decoded Token')
            print(token)
            id = decode_access_token(token)
            print(id)
            print(id)
            customer = models.Customer.objects.get(id=id)
            return (customer, None)
        raise exceptions.AuthenticationFailed('unauthenticated2')

def decode_access_token(token):
    try:
        payload = jwt.decode(token, 'access_secret', algorithms='HS256')
        print('accesstoken')
        print(payload)
        return payload['customer_id']
    except Exception as error :
        print('For token %s error detected %s', token, error)
        raise exceptions.AuthenticationFailed('unauthenticated1 ', error)

def create_access_token(id):
    print('AccessTokentime : ', current_time)
    print('access_token_expiry : ', access_token_expiry)
    return jwt.encode({
        'customer_id': id,
        'exp': access_token_expiry,
        'iat': current_time,
    }, 'access_secret', algorithm='HS256')
```

**urls.py**

```
    path('user/', UserDetails.as_view()),
```

**views.py**

```
class UserDetails(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    queryset = models.User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.UserSerializer
    authentication_classes = [ JWTAuthentication ]

    def get_queryset(self):
        qs = super().get_queryset()
        print('self.request.user.id ', self.request.user.id)
        customerObj = models.Customer.objects.get(id=self.request.user.id)
        print('customerObj ', customerObj.user.id)
        return qs.get(id=customerObj.user.id)
```

I am using Postman to make a request to URL **http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/user/** with header containing 'Authorization' key and 'Bearer ' value.
As seen in the view.py snippet, I see logs as
**self.request.user.id  2
customerObj  4**.

**Stacktrace:**

> Internal Server Error: /api/user/
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 55, in inner
> response = get_response(request)
> File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 197, in _get_response
> response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
> File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 56, in wrapper_view
> return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
> File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 104, in view
> return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
> File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 509, in dispatch
> response = self.handle_exception(exc)
> File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 469, in handle_exception
> self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
> File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 480, in raise_uncaught_exception
> raise exc
> File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 506, in dispatch
> response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
> File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/rest_framework/generics.py", line 282, in get
> return self.retrieve(request, *args, **kwargs)
> File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/rest_framework/mixins.py", line 54, in retrieve
> instance = self.get_object()
> File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/rest_framework/generics.py", line 88, in get_object
> assert lookup_url_kwarg in self.kwargs, (
> AssertionError: Expected view UserDetails to be called with a URL keyword argument named "pk". Fix your URL conf, or set the `.lookup_field` attribute on the view correctly.
> [30/Nov/2023 17:27:17] "GET /api/user/ HTTP/1.1" 500 97185

Comment: add lookup_field = 'id' under authentication_classes = [ JWTAuthentication ] in views.py file

Comment: @TanveerAhmad Tried this but now I am getting following error,





> Expected view UserDetails to be called with a URL keyword argument named "id". Fix your URL conf, or set the `.lookup_field` attribute on the view correctly.

Comment: did you changed your url like this path('some/<int:id>/', someView.as_view(), name='some-details') if uuid it will be str otherwise int

Comment: if you still face any kind of error look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51076123/django-rest-framework-generics-retrieveupdatedestroyapiview-return-all-records-i this answer will help you

Comment: I don't want to pass anything in the request URL, I am already passing identity with the token (in header). Is there no way to achieve this without passing any parameter? Am I missing something?

Comment: is there anything unique except id in your models? if unique then you can filter on them to retrieve update or delete that object.

Comment: Got it. Thanks I will try it out. I am quite new to Django so got confused. Thanks :)

Comment: I recommend you to use APIview and override them if you dont want to pass id or anything with url or in header to retrieve or update or delete. and then you get data on the base of request.user(current user) or request.data(data). You are welcome

Comment: Please edit your traceback so that is actually readable (e.g. use code formatting)